# How to access South County Trailway from Manhattan on a road bike?

Tags: bikeroutes

I'm interested in riding the [South Country Trailway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_County_Trailway) in New York. From reading on the internet, it appears that the trail is paved, but the paving promptly ends at the start of the trail in Van Cortlandt Park and turns into dirt. I'll be coming up through Manhattan (over the Broadway Bridge I guess).

I'm riding a road bike with ~25s. Is the path through the park ridable if going slow, or is there another way to the trailhead that I should use?

Comment: This question will need someone with local knowledge.

Comment: Just ride through -- it's not a gravel grinder or cyclocross race or whatever, it's a reasonably common bike commuter route. A non race bike (or even some race bikes) ridden not like a numpty shouldn't have problems.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say the paving _begins_ at the start of the trail.

Comment: Shouldn't be any problem with "dirt". I usually go on the road bike on dirt  roads, with 25's. The other day I put 28 with a little gripping thread and got so carried over I went up 3 kilometers of full throttle mountain track, all rocky and quite difficult ( going down would have been another story) but yes, road bikes can take much more than we usually expect. Just dont bring the carbon 6.133 kilo bike.. basic alu wheels that you wouldnt cry too much if they take a little damage